# Does a list of all Option Strategies exist? Where can I find it?

Tags: stocks, options, derivatives

There are a lot options strategies that are available. Is there a exhaustive count of option strategies? If yes, then where would we find such an list? Is it possible to get a list of all option strategies available?

Google did give me very good answers but not an exhaustive list. A lot of people have done research on this and based on my research there are a lot of strategies that are not known to general public and thus not on google. I am trying to find it anyone has any one knows a source which at least claims to be exhaustive.

All the strategies that are known publicly are discussed in many books, forums, websites. Given that all option strategies are permutations and combinations of a few basic moves, it should be possible to get an exhaustive list of all such permutations. While all permutations might not make profits in theory, a human mind will be needed to filter out the permutations that do not make profit even in theory. Has someone done this already?

Comment: Google would be a great place to start.

Comment: Google did give me very good answers but not an exhaustive list. A lot of people have done research on this and based on my research there are a  lot of strategies that are not known to general public and thus not on google. I am trying to find it anyone has any one knows a source which atleast claims to be exhaustive

Comment: I understand that understanding this topic will take time. However, discussion-style posts, or requests for resources, are not a good question format for this site. The Stackexchange network seeks direct, answerable questions; it's a bit different than a traditional forum.

Comment: Hmm.. i understand.. Thanks for taking time to explain how this site works.

Comment: An exhaustive list of all conceivable options strategies probably wouldn't benefit you much anyway.  The trick to trading is to be comfortable with what you're doing, not just pick a strategy.  Understand what options are.  Understand how they move, understand buying a put vs selling a call etc and what your ultimate responsibilities are in each case.  Understand how you can mitigate your risk with options, then think about how to use them.  The best place to start is the six or so common trade strategies.  Understand them, then massage them to suit your comfort and risk levels.

Comment: Google would be a horrible place to start, everyone else is wrong, you're welcome.

Comment: @CQM  Ironically, my google result offered me a book titled "The Bible of options strategies." (And I am the upvote on your answer below). That's a decent recommendation, not understanding why you don't care for the Google.

Comment: Unless you understand options WELL, don't touch them. They are, rather notoriously, a great way for novices to lose money.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer there's a lot of white noise, there is an intuitive way to learn about options, this was a good site to ask

Comment: Got it, it was in the spirit of "we don't need to send members away, when we can answer these." Much appreciated.

Comment: Your question is like asking for an all inclusive list of recipes that use salt or pepper. See the post of quid above.

Comment: The [CBOE](http://www.cboe.com/strategies) offers a comprehensive list of option strategies.

Answer (score 3):

A book I really enjoyed that opened my eyes to most combinations and the beauty of options was "The Bible of Options Strategies"

I had read a few abstract conceptual things about how options were supposed to work, and the beauty and utility completely missed the mark. Most talked about your profit at expiration when there are so many other *options* with options.

After that book, you really need to understand margin requirements and who is subject to them, so that you can synthesize your own strategies in different environments, or practically take advantages of nuances in volatility where the contract strike would seem to violate a practical margin requirement but be a decent opportunity regardless.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This is wonderful book on options. This does cover some strategies which are not available generally in any books/sites.I am yet to fully understand this book. I have updated the question a bit.  As someone who has understood the book better than me,please let me know if this book helped you devise your own permutations.

Comment: @RAVIDPARIKH - You've broken a rule of SE. In effect, you've edited to change the question itself. "Give me a reference" "Here it is" --- "Here's a new question". Not a big deal. I am rolling back the edit. You are encouraged to ask the new one, as a new question. I'd probably have answer to this new question.

Comment: Thanks @joetaxpayer. Did not know this. I also want to be careful that my new question is not counted as a duplicate question. Compared to other Q and A sites, this site seems to be very regulated and particular about rules.

Comment: Understood, SE has a tight on-topic policy across the boards here.